# Correct way to say "I only see you as a friend"

Tags: phrase-requests

How does one say "I only see you as a friend" in Japanese?
Literal translation would give 友達だけとして見ます, but the 見ます part seems awfully wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I **only** see you as a friend."

You'd use しか～ない for this "only".

Please refer to [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12596/9831) for the difference in nuance between だけ vs しか～ない.

You can form the sentence like this:

> "I see you as a friend." + "only"
>   = 「友達として見ています。」 + 「しか～ない」
>   → 「友達として**しか**見ていま**せん**。」

Example dialogue:

> Boy: 「好きです！付き合ってください！」
>   Girl: 「友達としてしか見られないの・・・ごめんなさい！」

Comment: Does this work well in situations where the Girl/Woman is trying to imply that they are not interested in a romantic relationship, or is there a more Japanese way to say that?

Comment: @ajsmart It will work well in such situations. Variants 「友達としか思ってない」「友達としか思えない」 or even 「友達としか…。」 will imply 恋愛対象外. 「一緒にいて楽しいけど、友達としてしか見れないし…ごめん。」とか言われたら、フラれたってことです。

Answer (score 1):

One phrase used to express this is

> 友達を超えない

Literally "(you) won't exceed being a friend".